# PostgresSql how to GROUP BY multiple columns and get all other columns aswell?

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I want to group by three columns and get the data from all columns.

This worked, but I don't get the data from lap.valid, lap."timestamp" and lap.maxspeed_kmh:

```
SELECT 
    players.name,
    cars.car,
    tracks.track,
    min(lap.laptime) AS best_laptime
FROM lap
    JOIN playerinsession ON lap.playerinsessionid = playerinsession.playerinsessionid
    JOIN session ON playerinsession.sessionid = session.sessionid
    JOIN tracks ON session.trackid = tracks.trackid
    JOIN cars ON playerinsession.carid = cars.carid
    JOIN players ON playerinsession.playerid = players.playerid
GROUP BY
    players.name,
    cars.car,
    tracks.track;
```

This is what I want to do:

```
SELECT 
    players.name,
    cars.car,
    tracks.track,
    min(lap.laptime) AS best_laptime,
    lap.valid,
    lap."timestamp",
    lap.maxspeed_kmh
FROM lap
    JOIN playerinsession ON lap.playerinsessionid = playerinsession.playerinsessionid
    JOIN session ON playerinsession.sessionid = session.sessionid
    JOIN tracks ON session.trackid = tracks.trackid
    JOIN cars ON playerinsession.carid = cars.carid
    JOIN players ON playerinsession.playerid = players.playerid
GROUP BY
    players.name,
    cars.car,
    tracks.track;
```

But I get an error "column lap.valid must appear in GROUP BY ...", how could I fix this?

The important thing is to get the fastest lap time for each player for each car and track combo. There are hundreds of lap times for each track done by multiple players in different cars.

Comment: you need to add lap.valid, lap.timestamp, lap.maxspeed_kmh in your group by too. But then the question is what you really want to get out of your query...

Comment: Yeah, I know that is possible, but I want the fastest lap for each player combined with each car and track. If I group by all parameters I get to many rows, right?
I will try @Clodoaldo Neto's answer when I get home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [`distinct on`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

```
select distinct on (p.name, c.car, t.track)
    p.name,
    c.car,
    t.track,
    l.laptime as best_laptime,
    l.valid,
    l."timestamp",
    l.maxspeed_kmh
from
    lap l
    join
    playerinsession on l.playerinsessionid = playerinsession.playerinsessionid
    join
    session on playerinsession.sessionid = session.sessionid
    join
    tracks t on session.trackid = t.trackid
    join
    cars c on playerinsession.carid = c.carid
    join
    players p on playerinsession.playerid = p.playerid
order by p.name, c.car, t.track, l.laptime
```

Comment: I tried DISTINCT in some way but never got it to work, but this worked like a charm! Thanks :)